# How to sort select2 autocompletion results, showing only items starting with first letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to modify the results in such a way that I match only words that start with the search term.

Here is my code thus far:

```js
var $elem = $( ".auto{!randomJsIden}" );

$elem.select2({
    sortresults:true,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    placeholder: "No value selected",
    allowClear : {!allowClear},
    query: function (query) {
         queryData{!randomJsIden}(query);
    },
    createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
         if ({!syncManualEntry} == true) {
             return {id:term, text:term};
         }
    }
});
```

Suppose I have fields values as apple, pineapple. When I type 'app' in the search field it should show only 'apple' in the results.

I am not well experienced in javascript. Let me know where I have to make modifications to achieve this sorted result.

Answer (score 0):

On the [Select2 examples page](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#matcher) it says that

> Unlike other dropdowns on this page, this one matches options only if the term appears in the beginning of the string as opposed to anywhere.
>   This custom matcher uses a compatibility module that is only bundled in the full version of Select2

You also have the option of using a more complex matcher.